# Regex- capturing punctuation and contractions

Tags: python, regex, punctuation

I am new to regexes, and I am trying write a function to break down a string into its contractions and punctuation.

For example: `I'm feeling sad today.`

should return a list: `["I","'m","feeling","sad","today","."]`.

So far I can only filter the letters with `([a-zA-Z])\w*` and I am not sure how I would filter this to include the punctuation.

Comment: So what about `feeling`?

Comment: I have made the edit

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

st = "I'm feeling sad today."

li = re.findall(r'\w+|[;.,!?:]|\'\w+',st)

['I', "'m", 'feeling', 'sad', 'today', '.']
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it using a findall ?

Comment: @NeptuneGamer, yes i have updated now with re.findall.

Comment: This is almost there but the ' is concatenated with the m

Comment: @NeptuneGamer take a look now

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for runs of characters which are either only word-characters, or neither word-characters nor whitespace:

```
>>> s = "I'm feeling sad today."
>>> rgx = re.compile(r'(\w+|[^\w\s]+)')
>>> rgx.findall(s)
['I', "'", 'm', 'feeling', 'sad', 'today', '.']
```

**EDIT**:

To capture contractions, the regexp needs to be more sophisticated. It must use a look-behind assertion to check that the apostrophe is preceeded by a word-character (otherwise it will wrongly match quoted words). Here's a basic solution:

```
>>> s = "I'm feeling 'sad' today."
>>> rgx = re.compile(r"((?<=\w)'\w+|\w+|[^\w\s]+)")
>>> rgx.findall(s)
['I', "'m", 'feeling', "'", 'sad', "'", 'today', '.']
```

There are some edge cases that this can't deal with, though. For instance, there are some transliterated foreign words (e.g. `Qur'an`) that contain embedded apostrophes. And then of course there are names like `O'Connor` and possessives such as `O'Connor's`, as well as non-standard contractions like `His 'n' Hers`.

Comment: I realise it may not be clear in the question but the apostrophe is joined to the letter ('m) and this is proving difficult to generate